# How to label a ternary plot

Tags: r, ternary

I am trying to create a triangular plot,that three dimensions of which represent three herbal strategies.
One dimension represents the strategy of C (competitive plant), the second dimension “S” (stress tolerant plants) and the third dimension ”R” (ruderal plants), the points on it represent the plant species.
I want to write the species name outside the triangle and connect it to the points inside the triangle with an arrow. How do I draw this ternary plot?

The following is the data structure and my code

```
require(Ternary)
TernaryPlot()

#Plot two stylised plots side by side, and plot data
par(mfrow=c(1, 1), mar=rep(0.3, 4))
TernaryPlot(atip='C%', btip='R%', ctip='S%',
        point='UP', lab.cex=0.8, grid.minor.lines=0,
        grid.lty='solid', col='#FFFFFF', grid.col='GREY', 
        axis.col=rgb(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), ticks.col=rgb(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
        padding=0.08)
data_points <- list("Bromus dantonia" = c(47,   59, 149),
                "Calamagrosis psoudo phragmatis" = c(90,    102,    63),
                "Carex diluta" = c(109, 64, 82),
                "Carex divisa" = c(96,  99, 59),
                "Carex pseudocyperus" = c(130,  71, 54),
                "Carex stenophylla" = c(97, 98, 59),
                "Catabrosa aquatica" = c(100,   5,  150),
                "Centaurea iberica" = c(124,    85, 46),
                "Cirsium hygrophilum" = c(158,  42, 55),
                "Cladium mariscus" = c(159, 96, 0),
                "cod2" = c(54,  82, 119),
                "Cynodon dactylon" = c(121, 54, 80),
                "Eleocharis palustri" = c(124,  100,    31),
                "Epilobium parviflorum" = c(67, 80, 107),
                "Eromopoa persica" = c(83,  15, 157),
                "Funaria cf.microstoma" = c(8,  0,  247),
                "Glaux maritime" = c(4, 196,    55),
                "Hordeum brevisubulatum" = c(76,    70, 109),
                "Hordeum glaucum" = c(40,   79, 136),
                "Inula britannica" = c(95,  108,    51),
                "Juncus articulatus" = c(107,   79, 69),
                "Blysmus compressus" = c(81,    127,    47),
                "Juncusinflexus"= c(149,    106,    0),
                "Medicago polymorpha" = c(60,   86, 109),
                "Mentha spicata" = c(150,   23, 82),
                "Ononis spinosa" = c(66,    112,    77),
                "Phragmites australis" = c(234, 0,  21),
                "Plantago amplexicaulis" = c(108,   83, 64),
                "Poa trivialis" = c(90, 28, 138),
                "Polygonum paronychioides" = c(20,  12, 223),
                "Potentila reptans" = c(106,    41, 108),
                "Potentilla anserina" = c(105,  58, 91),
                "Ranunculus grandiflorus" = c(129,  25, 101),
                "Schoenus nigricans" = c(143,   91, 21),
                "Setaria viridis" = c(10,   7,  238),
                "Sonchus oleraceus" = c(178,    0,  77),
                "Taraxacum officinale" = c(117, 28, 110),
                "Trifolium repens" = c(94,  4,  157),
                "Triglochin martima" = c(63,    96, 95),
                "Veronica anagallis-aquatica" = c(55,   37, 163)
)
AddToTernary(points, data_points, pch=21, cex=1.2, 
         bg=vapply(data_points, 
                   function (x) rgb(x[1], x[2], x[3], 128, 
maxColorValue=255),
                   character(1))
)

AddToTernary(text, data_points, names(data_points), cex=0.8, font=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Something to consider, you have a lot of information to add to the chart. I am concerned that the chart will become overly busy and unreadable adding that many labels.

Comment: Hi, thanks for consideration, If the name of the species is added to the triangle, the names of the species will overlap and cannot be read.
So I want the species name to be written out of the triangle and linked to the points inside the triangle by the arrow.